# Which API can implement tensor expansion in tensorflow ？

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have a tensor of (30,40,50), and I want to expand it out to the first order, then I get a second order tensor of (30,2000), and I don't know if tensorflow has an API that implements it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
data1=tf.constant([
    [[2,5,7,8],[6,4,9,10],[14,16,86,54]],
    [[16,43,65,76],[43,65,7,24],[15,75,23,75]]])

data5=tf.reshape(data1,[3,8])

data2,data3,data4=tf.split(data1,3,1)
data6=tf.reshape(data2,[1,8])
data7=tf.reshape(data3,[1,8])
data8=tf.reshape(data4,[1,8])
data9=tf.concat([data6,data7,data8],0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(data5))
    print(sess.run(data))
```

This gives:

```
data5
[[ 2 5 7 8 6 4 9 10]
[14 16 86 54 16 43 65 76]
[43 65 7 24 15 75 23 75]]

data9
[[ 2 5 7 8 16 43 65 76]
[ 6 4 9 10 43 65 7 24]
[14 16 86 54 15 75 23 75]]
```

How do I get data9 directly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to take the sub-tensors ranging across axis 0 (`data1[0]`, `data1[1]`, ...) and concatenate them along axis 2.

Transposing before reshaping should do the trick:

```
tf.reshape(tf.transpose(data1, [1,0,2]), [data1.shape[1], data1.shape[0] * data1.shape[2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`data9 = tf.layers.flatten(tf.transpose(data1, perm=[1, 0, 2]))`

Output:

```
array([[ 2,  5,  7,  8, 16, 43, 65, 76],
       [ 6,  4,  9, 10, 43, 65,  7, 24],
       [14, 16, 86, 54, 15, 75, 23, 75]], dtype=int32)
```